# Multiple unrelated queries in Neo4j Cypher?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Does `http://localhost:7474/browser/` not support multiple [***unrelated***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10880546/how-do-i-provide-multiple-queries-in-neo4j-cypher) queries?

This code:

```
MATCH (a {cond:'1'}), (b {cond:'x'}) CREATE a-[:rel]->b
MATCH (a {cond:'2'}), (b {cond:'y'}) CREATE a-[:rel]->b
MATCH (a {cond:'3'}), (b {cond:'z'}) CREATE a-[:rel]->b
```

causes an error:

> WITH is required between CREATE and MATCH

But since my queries aren't related, I don't think I shall need a `WITH`.

How do I do the above without having to enter it one-line-at-a-time?

Comment: [**LazyWebCypher**](http://www.lyonwj.com/LazyWebCypher/) is also one option for sending multiple queries

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In recent releases developers added an option in Neo4j Browser to execute multiple queries.

Open **Browser Settings** and click on **Enable multi statement query editor**.

Then just put semicolon on the end of each query and throw them all in browser console.

[image: Screenshot]

Here is how it looks

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 19):

As a work around you can do:

```
MATCH (a {cond:'1'}), (b {cond:'x'}) CREATE a-[:rel]->b
WITH 1 as dummy
MATCH (a {cond:'2'}), (b {cond:'y'}) CREATE a-[:rel]->b
WITH 1 as dummy
MATCH (a {cond:'3'}), (b {cond:'z'}) CREATE a-[:rel]->b
```

See also the import blog post: http://blog.neo4j.org/2014/01/importing-data-to-neo4j-spreadsheet-way.html

Comment: Be aware that the subqueries after `WITH 1 as dummy` will be executed once per row returned by the preceding query. Using an aggregation function like `WITH count(*) as dummy` will ensure the subsequent queries only execute once.

Answer (score 4):

You can send multiple queries to Neo4j via the cypher-shell command line tool:

```
cypher-shell --format plain < query.txt
```

where query.txt contains multiple independent queries separated by semi-colons. This also works interactively once you have started cypher-shell.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not aware of a way to send multiple unrelated queries at once via Neo4j browser. However on REST level this is perfectly possible by using the [transactional HTTP endpoint](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/rest-api-transactional.html).

Comment: Is there still no way to send multiple unrelated queries at once via Cypher and using the bolt drivers? I am assuming sending multiple unrelated queries, say 10, at once would perform better from a remote application compared to sending 10 queries one by one (not at the database level but from the application point of view)

Comment: on course you can send multiple cypher queries using bolt. Just acquire multiple session instances from your driver instance.

Comment: I am curious if there is a way to do it with one session instance. I dont want to occupy many sessions since it is an API and i want sessions to be available for other clients making calls. I want to be able to send all of them at once using one session instance, if there is a way. 

I would also really appreciate if you take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38112043/cypher-using-bolt-multiple-unrelated-queries-at-once-match-and-modify-set-p)