# Cypher (using bolt) multiple unrelated queries at once - match and modify (set property) of multiple nodes in single query

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have nodes of 5 different labels, say, `A, B, C, D, E`. I need to match a node of each type based on some property and update some other property of the matched node.

The query works perfectly fine if i execute 5 different `match and set` queries, one for each label type.

However, when I try to do everything in one single query, the property seems to get updated multiple times. The property I am updating is an array (the same value gets added to the array multiple times). The following is the query I am trying to execute:

```
match (a:A {a: "abc"}) 
match (A {a: "abc"})-[RELATED_TO*]-(b:B {b:"def"}) 
match (c:C {c: "lmn"}) 
match (d:D {d: "pqr"}) 
match (e:E {e: "xyz"}) 
set a.prop=a.prop+"123" 
set b.prop=b.prop+"123" 
set c.prop=c.prop+"123" 
set d.prop=d.prop+"123" 
set e.prop=e.prop+"123"
```

The issue is that when I execute the above query the property array `prop` gets `123` added multiple times. Is it because the results of my `match` statement are multiple and the same set statements are run that many times. If that is the case, can someone suggest me the best way to do this in a single query.

The reason I want to do this in a single query is because I am sending cypher queries from a remote application using Bolt protocol, and I do not want to send 5 different queries.

[EDIT : Adding a simple example]

Consider the following simple arrangement of all 5 nodes in the DB:
[image]

When I run the above query on this set up, and assuming the property `prop` was an empty array before, the following is the property value after running the query:

```
A.prop = ["123", "123", "123", "123", "123", "123", "123", "123"]  // added 8 times
B.prop = ["123", "123", "123", "123", "123", "123", "123", "123"]  // added 8 times
C.prop = ["123", "123", "123", "123"]  // added 4 times
D.prop = ["123", "123", "123", "123"]  // added 4 times
E.prop = ["123", "123", "123", "123"]  // added 4 times
```

The desired outcome however should be:

```
A.prop = ["123"]  // added 1 time
B.prop = ["123"]  // added 1 time
C.prop = ["123"]  // added 1 time
D.prop = ["123"]  // added 1 time
E.prop = ["123"]  // added 1 time
```

[Edit 2] I found a somewhat similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21778435/multiple-unrelated-queries-in-neo4j-cypher) but not a satisfying answer. I believe sending multiple unrelated queries at once from a remote application would be better than sending them one by one (from an application point of view)

Comment: "The property array prop gets 123 added multiple times". In all cases or just e.g in A and B entities. Ideally, consider adding a table with the desired outcome and the observed one.

Comment: Thanks, just updated my question