# Creation of multiple nodes in Neo4j using Cypher

Tags: database, graph, neo4j

I have a text file of cypher queries in the following format.

```
create(n:`0`{`78`:78, `127`:127, `336`:336, `346`:346, `349`:349, `55`:55, `255`:255, `61`:61, `354`:354, `356`:356, `97`:97, `361`:361, `338`:338, `217`:217, `348`:348, `53`:53, `61`:61, `92`:92, `3`:3, `210`:210, `54`:54, `352`:352, `354`:354, `209`:209, `3`:3, `210`:210, `345`:345, `72`:72, `360`:360, `361`:361, `209`:209, `340`:340, `72`:72, `352`:352, `359`:359, `97`:97, `2`:2, `344`:344, `345`:345, `255`:255, `65`:65, `67`:67, `77`:77, `344`:344, `350`:350, `92`:92, `338`:338, `337`:337, `340`:340, `55`:55, `97`:97, `14`:14, `342`:342, `255`:255, `356`:356, `357`:357, `77`:77, `335`:335, `344`:344, `351`:351, `355`:355, `360`:360, `337`:337, `348`:348, `77`:77, `3`:3, `53`:53, `352`:352, `97`:97, `209`:209, `14`:14, `338`:338, `347`:347, `348`:348, `354`:354, `209`:209, `14`:14, `338`:338, `3`:3, `343`:343, `255`:255, `354`:354, `97`:97, `360`:360, `341`:341, `72`:72, `92`:92, `338`:338, `347`:347, `61`:61, `64`:64, `65`:65, `352`:352, `353`:353, `354`:354, `355`:355, `361`:361, `2`:2, `340`:340, `343`:343, `351`:351, `355`:355, `209`:209, `335`:335, `338`:338, `339`:339, `346`:346, `348`:348, `64`:64, `71`:71, `77`:77, `78`:78, `351`:351, `72`:72, `359`:359, `337`:337, `217`:217, `53`:53, `55`:55, `351`:351, `355`:355, `356`:356, `77`:77, `217`:217, `339`:339, `348`:348, `349`:349, `53`:53, `351`:351, `67`:67, `357`:357, `77`:77, `3`:3, `335`:335, `351`:351, `352`:352, `336`:336, `347`:347, `348`:348, `55`:55, `350`:350, `255`:255, `359`:359, `209`:209, `2`:2, `53`:53, `54`:54, `72`:72, `353`:353, `2`:2, `14`:14, `342`:342, `344`:344, `255`:255, `354`:354, `355`:355, `77`:77, `97`:97, `360`:360, `361`:361, `209`:209, `336`:336, `345`:345, `348`:348, `349`:349, `65`:65, `2`:2, `3`:3, `340`:340, `342`:342, `71`:71, `72`:72, `92`:92, `97`:97, `337`:337, `347`:347, `64`:64, `65`:65, `357`:357, `360`:360, `339`:339, `342`:342, `351`:351, `361`:361, `337`:337, `342`:342, `64`:64, `358`:358, `2`:2, `342`:342, `346`:346, `348`:348, `54`:54, `350`:350, `61`:61, `64`:64, `359`:359, `92`:92, `97`:97, `360`:360, `336`:336, `341`:341, `217`:217, `53`:53, `350`:350, `353`:353, `347`:347, `349`:349, `357`:357, `3`:3, `210`:210, `336`:336, `346`:346, `349`:349, `355`:355, `356`:356, `358`:358, `353`:353, `360`:360, `348`:348, `65`:65, `71`:71, `2`:2, `341`:341, `344`:344, `350`:350, `352`:352, `353`:353, `92`:92, `360`:360, `345`:345, `64`:64, `65`:65, `2`:2, `340`:340, `341`:341, `67`:67, `359`:359, `336`:336, `345`:345, `351`:351, `255`:255, `61`:61, `217`:217, `339`:339, `55`:55, `14`:14, `61`:61, `355`:355, `357`:357, `336`:336, `340`:340, `342`:342, `354`:354, `337`:337, `348`:348, `71`:71, `97`:97, `3`:3, `217`:217, `55`:55, `350`:350, `351`:351, `352`:352});


create(n:`1`{`77`:77, `127`:127, `337`:337, `338`:338, `346`:346, `348`:348, `356`:356, `209`:209, `335`:335, `337`:337, `348`:348, `53`:53, `67`:67, `335`:335, `346`:346, `67`:67, `77`:77, `53`:53, `67`:67, `2`:2, `339`:339, `346`:346, `348`:348, `53`:53, `55`:55, `71`:71, `353`:353});


create(n:`2`{`35`:35, `53`:53, `55`:55, `57`:57, `78`:78, `92`:92, `98`:98, `114`:114, `126`:126, `135`:135});


create(n:`3`{`7`:7, `14`:14, `34`:34, `50`:50, `53`:53, `55`:55, `59`:59, `65`:65, `78`:78, `92`:92, `127`:127, `137`:137, `168`:168, `170`:170, 
`137`:137, `164`:164, `202`:202});


create(n:`4`{`50`:50, `53`:53, `55`:55, `56`:56, `78`:78, `127`:127});
```

and so on. 
This is a normal create syntax for Neo4j in Cypher.

I have 4038 such nodes.

Neo4j supposedly accepts one query at a time. Copying and pasting one query at a time is quite inefficient.

Also I have another file defining the relationships, which is around a 200000 in number. It is completely impractical to copy and paste one query at a time.

I need some help to automate the process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass a dummy variable using WITH to be able to do multiple queries at one time :

```
create(n:`0`{`78`:78, `127`:127, `336`:336, `346`:346, `349`:349, `55`:55, `255`:255, `61`:61, `354`:354, `356`:356, `97`:97, `361`:361, `338`:338, `217`:217, `348`:348, `53`:53, `61`:61, `92`:92, `3`:3, `210`:210, `54`:54, `352`:352, `354`:354, `209`:209, `3`:3, `210`:210, `345`:345, `72`:72, `360`:360, `361`:361, `209`:209, `340`:340, `72`:72, `352`:352, `359`:359, `97`:97, `2`:2, `344`:344, `345`:345, `255`:255, `65`:65, `67`:67, `77`:77, `344`:344, `350`:350, `92`:92, `338`:338, `337`:337, `340`:340, `55`:55, `97`:97, `14`:14, `342`:342, `255`:255, `356`:356, `357`:357, `77`:77, `335`:335, `344`:344, `351`:351, `355`:355, `360`:360, `337`:337, `348`:348, `77`:77, `3`:3, `53`:53, `352`:352, `97`:97, `209`:209, `14`:14, `338`:338, `347`:347, `348`:348, `354`:354, `209`:209, `14`:14, `338`:338, `3`:3, `343`:343, `255`:255, `354`:354, `97`:97, `360`:360, `341`:341, `72`:72, `92`:92, `338`:338, `347`:347, `61`:61, `64`:64, `65`:65, `352`:352, `353`:353, `354`:354, `355`:355, `361`:361, `2`:2, `340`:340, `343`:343, `351`:351, `355`:355, `209`:209, `335`:335, `338`:338, `339`:339, `346`:346, `348`:348, `64`:64, `71`:71, `77`:77, `78`:78, `351`:351, `72`:72, `359`:359, `337`:337, `217`:217, `53`:53, `55`:55, `351`:351, `355`:355, `356`:356, `77`:77, `217`:217, `339`:339, `348`:348, `349`:349, `53`:53, `351`:351, `67`:67, `357`:357, `77`:77, `3`:3, `335`:335, `351`:351, `352`:352, `336`:336, `347`:347, `348`:348, `55`:55, `350`:350, `255`:255, `359`:359, `209`:209, `2`:2, `53`:53, `54`:54, `72`:72, `353`:353, `2`:2, `14`:14, `342`:342, `344`:344, `255`:255, `354`:354, `355`:355, `77`:77, `97`:97, `360`:360, `361`:361, `209`:209, `336`:336, `345`:345, `348`:348, `349`:349, `65`:65, `2`:2, `3`:3, `340`:340, `342`:342, `71`:71, `72`:72, `92`:92, `97`:97, `337`:337, `347`:347, `64`:64, `65`:65, `357`:357, `360`:360, `339`:339, `342`:342, `351`:351, `361`:361, `337`:337, `342`:342, `64`:64, `358`:358, `2`:2, `342`:342, `346`:346, `348`:348, `54`:54, `350`:350, `61`:61, `64`:64, `359`:359, `92`:92, `97`:97, `360`:360, `336`:336, `341`:341, `217`:217, `53`:53, `350`:350, `353`:353, `347`:347, `349`:349, `357`:357, `3`:3, `210`:210, `336`:336, `346`:346, `349`:349, `355`:355, `356`:356, `358`:358, `353`:353, `360`:360, `348`:348, `65`:65, `71`:71, `2`:2, `341`:341, `344`:344, `350`:350, `352`:352, `353`:353, `92`:92, `360`:360, `345`:345, `64`:64, `65`:65, `2`:2, `340`:340, `341`:341, `67`:67, `359`:359, `336`:336, `345`:345, `351`:351, `255`:255, `61`:61, `217`:217, `339`:339, `55`:55, `14`:14, `61`:61, `355`:355, `357`:357, `336`:336, `340`:340, `342`:342, `354`:354, `337`:337, `348`:348, `71`:71, `97`:97, `3`:3, `217`:217, `55`:55, `350`:350, `351`:351, `352`:352})

WITH 1 as whatever

create(n:`1`{`77`:77, `127`:127, `337`:337, `338`:338, `346`:346, `348`:348, `356`:356, `209`:209, `335`:335, `337`:337, `348`:348, `53`:53, `67`:67, `335`:335, `346`:346, `67`:67, `77`:77, `53`:53, `67`:67, `2`:2, `339`:339, `346`:346, `348`:348, `53`:53, `55`:55, `71`:71, `353`:353})
```

and so on...

You can check this example for more informations: [Multiple unrelated queries in Neo4j Cypher?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21778435/multiple-unrelated-queries-in-neo4j-cypher)

All you have to do is C/P `WITH 1 as dummy` between each one of your request, then you have one big request.

Comment: Trying this gave me an error of, "Expected exactly one statement per query but got: 4040"

Comment: oh nvm, you also have to remove `;` at the end of your create statements. I fixed the example.

Comment: Yes, thank you, that worked. However, it worked for a small database. As i entered all 4038 queries together, it ran for some time and gave me the error  "Neo.DatabaseError.General.UnknownError".

Comment: It comes from the fact that all your queries at one are really doing too much work for one query. Therefore you should split it in multiple queries, but it'll still be less than every queries one by one. Else you can look for the HTTP transation endpoint solution provided in the question I linked to you below.

Comment: Yes, I realized that much and I am splitting 100 queries at a time. Thank you so much.