# Running multiple statements in one query using Drivine and Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, nestjs, drivine

I am trying to run four statements in one query to the database. It gives me an error message saying only one statement per query is possible.

Is this possible with Drivine using Neo4j? If it is a setting, where can I find it and what value does it need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The database client, in this case Drivine, is not really relevant here because this is a limitation of Neo4j and its drivers.

To run multiple statements in just one query there are two options that come to my mind:

- Insert `WITH 1 as dummy` between each statement. See this anser for an example:
  https://stackoverflow.com/a/21810903/1967693
- Run your statements with [apoc.cypher.runMany](https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/4.1/overview/apoc.cypher/apoc.cypher.runMany/)

Comment: Ah, I figured they would have it supported considering the "allow running multiple queries" option has been in the neo4j browser for many years. Thank you for your answer